# CentOS7 hadoop wordcount with exit code 127

Tags: java, hadoop, centos, hadoop-yarn

There was a problem when I tried to execute the wordcount program

**Results after operation：**

```
2021-03-06 10:46:36,826 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2021-03-06 10:46:36,845 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1614998747877_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1614998747877_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1614998747877_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 127
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2021-03-06 10:46:36.605]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1614998747877_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 127

[2021-03-06 10:46:36.645]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
/bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory


[2021-03-06 10:46:36.646]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
/bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory


For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://hadoop103:8088/cluster/app/application_1614998747877_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

**Next is the information in the web page：**

```
Application application_1614998747877_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1614998747877_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: 127
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2021-03-06 10:46:36.605]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1614998747877_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 127
[2021-03-06 10:46:36.645]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
/bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory
[2021-03-06 10:46:36.646]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 127. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
Last 4096 bytes of stderr :
/bin/bash: /bin/java: No such file or directory
For more detailed output, check the application tracking page: http://hadoop103:8088/cluster/app/application_1614998747877_0001 Then click on links to logs of each attempt.
. Failing the application.
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

solved

need to add JAVA_HOME path to hadoop-env.sh

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujfqd.png)